# Alias extraction in DB2

Tags: db2

"db2look -d database_name -e -v view_name"
The above command is used to extract the ddl for  views in db2.
Similarly, how to extract the ddl for the alias name in views?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a recent (Db2 v11.5 or higher) version of Db2-LUW,
you can use the `-t` option to specify the view name (instead of the `-v` option) because the `-t` option will extract all the dependent objects of the specified object, including aliases.

But the `-v` option is documented as NOT extracting any dependent objects.

You can also query the Db2-LUW catalog tables to extract the alias creation statments for views.

for example, the query below extracts any alias for any VIEW object, excluding SYS% objects, and you can adjust as needed for whatever schema(s) you are interested in .

```
select 'create alias '||rtrim(t1.tabschema) || '.' || rtrim(t1.tabname)||'  FOR '||rtrim(t1.base_tabschema)||'.'||rtrim(t1.base_tabname)||' ;'
from syscat.tables t1
inner join syscat.views v1
on t1.base_tabschema = v1.viewschema
and t1.base_tabname = v1.viewname
where    t1.type='A'
and      t1.base_tabschema not like 'SYS%'
order by 1 asc with ur;
```